# Is high gelatin concentration in cheesecake unsafe? 

Tags: food-safety, gelatin, cheesecake

I made a home made no bake cheesecake tonight. The cream would not thicken so I added extra gelatin.

Is it safe to eat? How long can I keep it in the fridge?

The ingredients are:

- 1 egg
- white sugar
- sour cream
- double cream
- cream cheese
- lemon juice
- 2 sachets of powdered gelatin

It's been in the fridge for 3 hours. It has set, but I'm not sure if it's safe to eat because of the extra gelatin powder.

Comment: Dear louise, welcome to SA. I changed the formatting of your question to make it easier to read, but preserved the original meaning. You can see your old version in the edit history, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/posts/20287/revisions.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely safe to eat. Gelatin is a normal part of animal meat and bones, and you get it in large amounts when you cook tough pieces of meat slowly. It is not toxic or dangerous, even in large concentrations.

The amount of gelatin does not change the time your cake will last, so you can treat it as a normal cheesecake. To see how long it keeps, it is best to [use a database like stilltasty](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16748).

*Edit* Stilltasty assumes a baked cheesecake. As noted in the comments, the raw egg reduces the shelf life of the cheesecake. My best guess is that it will keep up to four days (based on the shelf life of other raw-egg preparations), but I am not a specialist for that, if in doubt, it is better to use it up sooner.

Comment: Just wondering if the raw egg might make a different from regular cheesecake since its no bake...

Comment: @Jay: That doesn't have anything to do with the gelatin. But: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2957/is-it-safe-to-eat-raw-eggs

Comment: @jay Good point, I concentrated a lot on the gelatin and forgot that the egg goes into the cheese mass and not into a layer. Then I would say it is probably similar to mayonnaise and other raw egg products, up to 4 days.

Comment: @Jefromi: My comment was in reference to rumtscho's answer in regards to his additional information about shelf life. That's why the comment is in this answer rather than on the question.

Comment: If anything, more gelatin will _increase_ the storage life because it reduces Available Water. However, the rule of thumb for refrigerated raw egg is three days.