# Is it safe to use raw eggs in icecream as in the Dukan recipe?

Tags: food-safety, safety, recipe-changing

I've seen [Dukan's icecream recipe](https://www.mydukandiet.com/recipes/chocolate-ice-cream.html) on several sites and nowhere they say to boil or otherwise cook the eggs, only to mix the yolks with the sweetener, and to whip the whites. I thought it isn't safe to raw eat animal derived food frozen in a home freezer as it may not kill infections (like fish flesh: it should be frozen according to safety standards before it can be safely consumed as raw).

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  A lot of recipes for all kinds of different foods use uncooked eggs.  A lot of foods people regularly eat are not "safe".  That said, traditional ice cream recipes that include eggs *do* often cook the eggs, in order to make a custard base.

Comment: @Juhasz my question is isn't it unsafe or may be I miss something? By the way what are those unsafe regular foods?

Comment: If you just search raw eggs you’ll find lots of answers but in short if you are using eggs that are fresh, (and refrigerated for the USA) then you should be just fine. Bacteria don’t just magically appear. They need the right conditions and time to grow.

Comment: If you're concerned about using raw eggs, you can get cartons of 'liquid eggs', which are pasteurized.  Just make sure to get "whole eggs" and not the ones that are egg whites.  You can also get pasteurized eggs still in their shell, but they're harder to find.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to eat raw eggs?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2957/is-it-safe-to-eat-raw-eggs) That question starts out talking about raw eggs by themselves but also addresses raw egg as an ingredient in other recipes.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without seeing the recipe you are referring to. Most ice cream bases are cooked to form a custard, so are not raw. If you can edit with a recipe then your question would be clearer.